# NSIS cancel messagebox with bad content

Tags: nsis, messagebox, abort

I have page where I download some files. Sometimes, when I press cancel in this page, I see MessageBox with bad text, look likes some numbers or some parts of word. But I used `MUI_ABORTWARNING_TEXT`.

Why I see bad text instead my `ABORTWARNING_TEXT`?

```
!define MUI_ABORTWARNING_TEXT "Are you sure you want to quit ${PRODUCT_NAME} Setup?"
!define MUI_CUSTOMFUNCTION_ABORT "CustomAbort"

Function CustomAbort

        ${If} ${Cmd} `MessageBox MB_YESNO "${MUI_ABORTWARNING_TEXT}" IDYES`
        # do smth
        ${Else}
        Abort
        ${EndIf}

    FunctionEnd
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTf0W.png)

Comment: Which download plug-in are you using?

Comment: I used   ExecDos::exec

Comment: Please post your ExecDos command.

Comment: ExecDos::exec /NOUNLOAD /ASYNC /TOFUNC `${TEMPDIR}\wget -S --tries=3 --timeout=5 --no-check-certificate --http-user=******* --http-password=****-O ******"$THIS_SERVER_HTTPS:$THIS_PORT/win$THIS_ARCH$THIS_SPECIFIER?script_version=$THIS_SCRIPTVERSION&version=$THIS_OSVERSION&hostname=$THIS_HOSTNAME"` "" $R2

Comment: And this message is in a popup? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: I posted a screenshot above. But this message can be with other numbers or some text.

Comment: To narrow it down, can you put MessageBoxes before and after ExecDos: `MessageBox mb_ok "Before" ExecDos::... MessageBox mb_ok "After"` (on separate lines) and verify that the strange MessageBox occurs between those two? I will investigate ExecDos tonight...

Comment: I think it can be because I used BgWorker::Call Wait for download. It can change stack or global variables and messagebox shows bad string in this moment. How is stack behavior in async mode?

Comment: The main thread does nothing while waiting but maybe there is a incompatibility between BgWorker and ExecDos (unlikely). Why can't you use InetC instead of ExecDos + wget? And why /ASYNC if it is already on a background thread?